# does viewPager change my pages different on different devices?

Tags: android

On some devices i see that the Fragment order is 1,2,3,4 
and other is 2,3,4,1

How to fix it ?

The code

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "1");                  // 1
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "2");              // 2
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(), "3");                // 3
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment4(), "4");                // 3

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> _fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> _fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return _fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _fragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        _fragmentList.add(fragment);
        _fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return _fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> _fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> _fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, List<Fragment> _fragmentList, List<String> _fragmentTitleList) {
        super(manager);
        this._fragmentList = _fragmentList;
        this._fragmentTitleList = _fragmentTitleList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return _fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return _fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

And use it .

```
List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

// add fragment
fragmentList.add(new Fragment1());
fragmentList.add(new Fragment2());
fragmentList.add(new Fragment3());
fragmentList.add(new Fragment4());

// add title
fragmentTitleList.add("1");
fragmentTitleList.add("2");
fragmentTitleList.add("3");
fragmentTitleList.add("4");

ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList, fragmentTitleList);

viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```